# Python How to force object instantiation via Context Manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I want to force object instantiation via class context manager. So make it impossible to instantiate directly.

I implemented this solution, but technically user can still instantiate object.

```
class HessioFile:
    """
    Represents a pyhessio file instance
    """
    def __init__(self, filename=None, from_context_manager=False):
        if not from_context_manager:
            raise HessioError('HessioFile can be only use with context manager')
```

And context manager:

```
@contextmanager
def open(filename):
    """
    ...
    """
    hessfile = HessioFile(filename, from_context_manager=True)
```

Any better solution ?

Comment: What is the reason to prevent the class to be instantiated?

Comment: The reason is to avoid that user to not close file that is open in __init__

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you consider that your clients will follow basic python coding principles then you can guarantee that no method from your class will be called if you are not within the context.

Your client is not supposed to call `__enter__` explicitly, therefore if `__enter__` has been called you know your client used a `with` statement and is therefore inside context (`__exit__` will be called).

You just need to have a boolean variable that helps you remember if you are inside or outside context.

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self._inside_context = False

    def __enter__(self):
        self._inside_context = True
        print("Entering context.")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print("Exiting context.")
        self._inside_context = False

    def some_stuff(self, name):
        if not self._inside_context:
            raise Exception("This method should be called from inside context.")
        print("Doing some stuff with", name)

    def some_other_stuff(self, name):
        if not self._inside_context:
            raise Exception("This method should be called from inside context.")
        print("Doing some other stuff with", name)


with Obj() as inst_a:
    inst_a.some_stuff("A")
    inst_a.some_other_stuff("A")

inst_b = Obj()
with inst_b:
    inst_b.some_stuff("B")
    inst_b.some_other_stuff("B")

inst_c = Obj()
try:
    inst_c.some_stuff("c")
except Exception:
    print("Instance C couldn't do stuff.")
try:
    inst_c.some_other_stuff("c")
except Exception:
    print("Instance C couldn't do some other stuff.")
```

This will print:

```
Entering context.
Doing some stuff with A
Doing some other stuff with A
Exiting context.
Entering context.
Doing some stuff with B
Doing some other stuff with B
Exiting context.
Instance C couldn't do stuff.
Instance C couldn't do some other stuff.
```

Since you'll probably have many methods that you want to "protect" from being called from outside context, then you can write a decorator to avoid repeating the same code to test for your boolean:

```
def raise_if_outside_context(method):
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._inside_context:
            raise Exception("This method should be called from inside context.")
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Then change your methods to:

```
@raise_if_outside_context
def some_other_stuff(self, name):
    print("Doing some other stuff with", name)
```

Comment: Now that type checkers have become more popular, it should be noted that this approach provides a runtime solution, but no type checking time solution, i.e., type checkers could not detect "wrong" usages. @Laurent Chriqui's solution has the benefit of being detectable by type checkers as well, at the cost of adding a layer of indirection.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the following approach:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._class = _MainClass(*args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        print('entering...')
        return self._class

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Teardown code
        print('running exit code...')
        pass


# This class should not be instantiated directly!!
class _MainClass:
    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2
        ...

    def method(self):
        # execute code
        if self.attribute1 == "error":
            raise Exception
        print(self.attribute1)
        print(self.attribute2)


with MainClass('attribute1', 'attribute2') as main_class:
    main_class.method()
print('---')
with MainClass('error', 'attribute2') as main_class:
    main_class.method()
```

This will outptut:

```
entering...
attribute1
attribute2
running exit code...
---
entering...
running exit code...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_6.py", line 34, in <module>
    main_class.method()
  File "scratch_6.py", line 25, in method
    raise Exception
Exception
```

Answer (score 2):

None that I am aware of.  Generally, if it exists in python, you can find a way to call it.  A context manager is, in essence, a resource management scheme... if there is no use-case for your class outside of the manager, perhaps the context management could be integrated into the methods of the class?  I would suggest checking out the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/atexit.html) module from the standard library.  It allows you to register cleanup functions much in the same way that a context manager handles cleanup, but you can bundle it into your class, such that each instantiation has a registered cleanup function.  Might help.

It is worth noting that no amount of effort will prevent people from doing stupid things with your code.  Your best bet is generally to make it as easy as possible for people to do smart things with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of hacky ways to *try* and enforce this (like inspecting the call stack to forbid direct calls to your object, boolean attribute that is set upon `__enter__` that you check before allowing other actions on the instance) but that will eventually become a mess to understand and explain to others.

Irregardless, you should also be certain that people will always find ways to bypass it if wanted. Python doesn't really tie your hands down, if you want to do something silly it lets you do it; responsible adults, right?

If you need an enforcement, you'd be better off supplying it as a documentation notice. That way if users opt to instantiate directly and trigger unwanted behavior, it's their fault for not following guidelines for *your code*.