# Enforce the use of context manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, contextmanager

I have a custom resource defined as a class and a context manager to manage that resource. This combination is working perfectly. Is there any way to enforce that the resource will be used through context manager only and if anything is there then is that Pythonic?

**Update:**

I have tested one idea what seems to be working perfectly. But I am not very sure, whether this is a good idea or not, though, I haven't found any drawback by my own. Wanted to check the opinion of the python experts.

Idea: As my resource is a custom resource, I have included a check there to ensure it is getting managed by a resource manager.

```
class Resource:
    def __init__(self, name, resource_manager):
        rm = isinstance(resource_manager, ResourceManager)
        if not rm:
            raise Exception("Resource must be managed by the resource manager")
        else:
            ........
            ........
            ........
```

And in the resource manager, I am doing something like below:

```
class ResourceManager:
    def __init__(self, resource_name):
        self.resource = Resource(resource_name, self)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.resource
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        ......
        ......
```

Comment: Your question is very vague, but in principle it sounds possible. Please provide a [mre] demonstrating what you want to achive (and any attempt you have made to do so).

Comment: Not really enforced but you can give the resource class a name beginning with an underscore and write into docs that it shouldn't be used directly. Then you can create a wrapper class (or just a wrapper function with "contextlib.contextmanager") providing the context manager which will internally handle creation and close of the resource object.

Comment: Highly related or possible duplicate of: [Python How to force object instantiation via Context Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40301963/1804173)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No, you can't force use of context management.

**Long answer:** You *could* have entering the context manager set state on the instance that is checked whenever the instance is used, and have failure to set that state raise an exception. It won't work if the object has no other methods called though. The other thing you can do is have state that indicates if the object has been cleaned by `__exit__`, and use [the `warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) to raise a `ResourceWarning` when the object is garbage-collected without `__exit__` being called. This can be done either by implementing `__del__` or by using [`weakref.finalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize), either of which can perform final checks when the object is garbage-collected.

As far as what's "Pythonic", the best I can tell you is that the `ResourceWarning` on garbage-collection trick is what Python itself uses to inform people when open file handles are not properly closed, either via `__exit__` or via the `close` method, before they are collected. It's not a perfect solution (the default warnings filter never tells you about `ResourceWarning`s, so your users have to opt-in), but unless context management is the *only* reasonable way to use your class (unusual; even file objects can reasonably be used in ways that context management can't cover), it's the nicest way to do it: Low overhead, low verbosity for people who don't care, but visible to developers who need to debug issues.