# Python recursion: Why no new object is instantiated?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

The following is a simplified example of a problem I ran into recently, and even though I circumvented it by rewriting my code, I still do not understand why it happened.

Consider the following python script:

```py
class Configer(object):
    
    def __init__(self, pops_cfg = {}):
        self.pops_cfg = pops_cfg
        
    
    def add_pop(self, name, gs):
        pop_cfg = {}
        pop_cfg['gs'] = gs
        
        if name in self.pops_cfg:
            self.pops_cfg[name].update(pop_cfg)
        else:
            self.pops_cfg[name] = pop_cfg
        
    def get(self):
        return self.pops_cfg
    

def get_config(name):    
    if name == 'I':
        c = Configer()
        c.add_pop('I', 100)
        
    elif name == 'IE':
        c = get_config('I')
        c.add_pop('E', 200)
    
    else:
        raise
        
    return c
```

with these test cases:

```py
# test 1
a = get_config('I')
print(a, id(a), a.get())
# <__main__.Configer object at 0x7fa83615c580> 140360438629760 {'I': {'gs': 100}}


# test 2
b = get_config('IE')
print(b, id(b), b.get())
# <__main__.Configer object at 0x7fa83603f610> 140360437462544 {'I': {'gs': 100}, 'E': {'gs': 200}}


# test 3
c = get_config('I')
print(c, id(c), c.get())
# <__main__.Configer object at 0x7fa83603c280> 140360437449344 {'I': {'gs': 100}, 'E': {'gs': 200}}
```

The first and second tests behave as I expect, adding two dictionaries with keys `I` and [`I`,`E`], respectively. However, the last one, which is identical to the first, surprisingly (to me) has both keys. I understand what is happening, but don't understand why.

## What is happening

Here, even in the second test has some flaws. In it **the internal `get_config('I')` call does not create a new instance of the `Configer` object. Instead, it updates the one created earlier for the first test `a = get_config('I')`**. Similarly, the last test does not create a new object but updates the previously created one, i.e. the variable `c` which has both `I` and `E` as its `pops_cfg` keys after execution of the second test.

## What I don't understand

I'm curious to know why bolded the part in the last paragraph is happening. In particular, I thought the way the if/elif statements is written, would force both `name==I` and `name==IE` tests to construct a base case (associated with `name==I`) and then update it according to the needs. It's not happening though.

Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: You may need to explore the use of the Python context manager in this case. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301963/python-how-to-force-object-instantiation-via-context-manager